# Запуск Andriod Studio на windows 7 без прав администратора

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7

Если запускать Andriod Studio на windows 7 без прав администратора, то появляется вот такая ошибка при старте студии:

> Files in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\system\caches are locked
> Andriod Studio will not able to start up.

При чем, кнопка ОК неактивна.

http://f4.s.qip.ru/adNBVlRg.png

Comment: Удалил я старую версию. Скачал и установил новую версию Android studio - 0.3.2


Android studio теперь устанавливается хитро - в локальный профиль пользорвателя C:\Users\AppData\..... в общем, как и гуглохром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поспешил, уже нашёл ответ:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856650/android-studio-failed-to-open-by-giving-error-files-locked

---

**Перевод**

---

Решение в windows-7:

1. Перейдите в папку куда установлен android-studio. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio)
2. Вернитесь на папку выше (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android)
3. Правый клик на папке android-studio вкладка «Свойства»
4. В окне свойств выберите вкладку «Безопасность»
5. Нажмите кнопку «Изменить»
6. В новом открывшемся окне, выберите имя Вашего пользователя (группу)
7. В списке ниже поставьте галочку "Allow" напротив "Полный доступ"
8. Теперь нажмите "OK", потом снова "OK"
9. Готово. Теперь Вы можете запускать Android Studio без прав администратора. Благодарности Ali